# Como exibir foto salva no banco de dados?

Tags: php, mysql, imagem

Gente, como eu faço para exibir fotos salvas no meu banco de dados? Pretendo fazer como uma galeria que tenha a opção de o administrador excluir a foto ou adicionar uma nova quando quiser.

Comment: Você pode postar o código que você tem aí ou como é a tabela onde as fotos estão salvas? Fica mais fácil pra comunidade te ajudar. :)

Comment: Renan, geralmente o que se faz é guardar o caminho relativo da imagem no banco de dados e com ele exibir a imagem quando preciso. É possível guardar a imagem em um banco de dados, porém é totalmente desaconselhável por questões lógicas de performance.

Comment: Então o que seria aconselhável para fazer a galeria de fotos que o adm possa editar?